# Python, how to check if file exists on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I was hoping to find an alternative way to check if a file exists on Windows 10.

Basically, if I have a filename, I want to be able to confirm the device has that file in C drive.

Many recommended using os.walk() to search all C drive, but it takes way too much time.

Can you suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why would you expect that it can be done much faster?

Comment: Well, Windows has some sort of search index for it's drives. It is as least thinkable that Microsoft offers some API to access that search index. Have you done any research in this direction?

Comment: I've seen solutions that call File Explorer via Subprocess, then searching a file through the explorer. However, I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require actually calling the explorer UI. Preferrably done by API response to check if the a file exists.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer depends on [Windows Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-overview#windows-search-sdk-documentation), And There is a lib for python  on github:

[winsearch](https://github.com/micrkernel/winsearch)

Or use SQL:

```
import win32com.client

pattern = "test.txt"
path = "C:\\%"
con = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
rs  = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
print(path)
con.Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';")
rs.Open("SELECT System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE System.FileName LIKE '" + pattern + "' AND System.ItemPathDisplay LIKE '" + path + "'" , con)
num = 0
while not rs.EOF:
    print(rs.Fields.Item("System.ItemPathDisplay").Value)
    num += 1
    rs.MoveNext()
if(num == 0):
    print("not exist")
```

Or use another lib: [`scandir`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir#background) instead of `os.walk()`, which is said 7-50 times faster than `os.walk()` on Windows.